# jQuery nested callback "ignoring" a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animation sequence that I am trying to implement in which I will:

1. fadeout a div,
2. change its position
3. change its background
4. fade it in
5. slide it to the right , increment my background counter and start over

I used a nested callback however despite the sequence seemingly running smoothly, well at least that's what my terminal reports it seems the div just won't apply the styling i.e. the background image. please do help debug and **if I could get the same implementation using promises that would really help as well**

```js
var bgs = ["1.png", "2.jpg", "3.png"] //image paths
var i = 0 //image pointer/counter

function changebg() {
  $(".m").fadeOut(1000, () => {
    $(".m").animate(({
      "margin-left": "0px"
    }), () => {
      $(".m").css(("background-image", bgs[i]), () => {
        $(".m").fadeIn(1000, () => {
          $(".m").animate(({
            "margin-left": "200px"
          }), 1000, () => {
            if (i == 2) i = 0
            else i++
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: It would help to see the HTML in order to create a working example. However I can tell you that `css()` doesn't have a callback function, and you don't need half of the callback functions you have as the element is not visible at that point.

Comment: the fade out is to eliminate the flickering of the images when I am switching from one to the other ,and also to reset the position the div since the animation will be looping is there a better implementation? . yea and the html is just a 200*200px div didn't really think it was relevant to the problem  .

Comment: ouh it dos not have a callback , thanks for that , how then would  go about it using callbacks

Answer (score 0):

The reason your current solution doesn't apply the background is due to the line:

> ```
> $(".m").css(("background-image", bgs[i]), () => {
> ```

[`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value) expects a property and a value. `("background-image", bgs[i])` is a [comma separated list of expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and evaluates to the result of the last expression. So the above is equivalent to:

```
$(".m").css(bgs[i], () => {
```

Furthermore, `css()` also doesn't except a callback, since it is expected to be applied immediately (not taking into account CSS transitions).

This line should be:

```
$(".m").css("background-image", bgs[i]); // also removing the closing })
```

---

You can convert the jQuery [`fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), [`fadeIn()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to [jQuery deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) by using [`promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).

A jQuery deferred object is "thenable" (i.e. has a ["then" method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)) and can thus be used with the [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (or with [`Promise.resovle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)).

I'm not sure if my example covers what you are trying to do, but this is what I got from your provided scenario:

```js
async function cycleBackgrounds($element, backgrounds) {
  while (true) {
    for (const background of backgrounds) {
      await $element.fadeOut(1000).promise();
      await $element.animate({"margin-left": "0px"}).promise();
      $element.css("background-color", background);
      await $element.fadeIn(1000).promise();
      await $element.animate({"margin-left": "200px"}).promise();
    }
  }
}

const promise = cycleBackgrounds($(".m"), ["red", "green", "blue"]);
//    ^ The returned promise will never be resolved, since the function
//      will cycle endlessly. You might still want to add a .catch though.
```

```css
.m {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a bunch!  works perfectly all I need to do is get the sense of things as I not quite good with promises as yet

Comment: If you want to familiarize yourself with promises I suggest starting out by reading the [MDN Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) guide. jQuery deferred objects are thenable, but not native JavaScript promises. Learning plain JavaScript first is in my opinion more beneficial, you can have a look at the jQuery deferred object later.